# React Checkbox Component not saving state to LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, state, react-component

I am creating a component in React which includes a checkbox. I want it to toggle back and forth (on and off) and save the state in local storage so if I go to another page, the toggle will be set to what it was before.

**Note: I am not using React 16 and can not use state hooks**

I created my component and added the `ComponentDidMount` and `ComponentDidUpdate` functions as below.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Checkbox } from 'semantic-ui-react'

type Props = {
    label : string
}

type State = {
    status: boolean
}



class ChangeOrder extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            status: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        localStorage.getItem('status') && this.setState({
            status: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('status'))
        })
    }

    

    componentDidUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        localStorage.setItem('status', JSON.stringify(nextState.status));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            
            <Checkbox
                
                onClick={() => this.setState({ status: !status })}
                label={this.props.label}        
                toggle

            />
        );
    }
}

export default ChangeOrder;
```

The checkbox works but it does not save the state.

When I right click to inspect and go to `Application` and navigate to `LocalStorage`, I see the value of the toggle switch go from false to true but clicking it again does not return it to false.

I want to be able to save and persist the toggle button state between true and false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the status on click event from the state to be `this.state.status`, pass the `status` value to `checked` prop to ensure the input has the expected value. Also, I prefer not to use stringify the boolean values instead, evaluate the string boolean value to boolean type. I built an app to check out on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-checkbox-component-not-saving-state-to-localstorage-xngqu?file=/src/ChangeOrder.tsx).

Comment: Hi, thanks this made it go from false to true and then back to false in the local storage but how do I make it persist that state if I were to refresh the page?

Comment: OK, I updated the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-checkbox-component-not-saving-state-to-localstorage-xngqu?file=/src/ChangeOrder.tsx) and it's working now according to your reply. Please check the component there.

Answer (score 0):

i think your missing this.status in your **Checkbox** click function
change

```
onClick={() => this.setState({ status: !status })}
```

to

```
onClick={() => this.setState({ status: !this.state.status })}
```